# Emacs 26.3 on macOS quits unexpectedly when using arrow keys

Tags: osx, crash

I have just installed emacs on my system and am having a problem where it quits when I am opening a new file. Here's how it happens:

After I open emacs I click the "blank page" icon. Next, the file explorer opens. When I try to navigate anywhere in the explorer using the arrow keys emacs instantly closes and Apple gives me an "emacs has quit unexpectedly" message. If I reopen the program and navigate by clicking I am able to open a file with no problem, only the arrow keys cause it to close.

I am running Mac OS 10.15.6 and emacs 26.3. Has anyone else encountered this? I am brand new to this program.

Comment: How did you install Emacs?

Comment: I installed from: www.emacsformacosx.com

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the issue without any user configuration, aka `emacs -q`, then you may wish to see if the issue is present in either the upcoming Emacs 27 and/or bleeding edge Emacs 28 versions.  In general, when Emacs crashes, it is helpful to catch it with `gdb` -- this requires building from source, and launching Emacs under `gdb` from the `src` directory of the build repository -- then, you can run a detailed backtrace that can help Alan Third (macOS Emacs port maintainer) and others on the development team look into the issue.

Comment: Any crash (and this does sound like an Emacs crash) reflects a bug, and it should be reported. Please use `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a step-by-step recipe to repro it, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into both of those. Working on reporting it too.